# html5 video cueChange

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am using VTT cues in html5 video. I am trying to figure out if there is an event that fires when a new subtitle displays on the screen.  I have found the "cueChange" event but it doesn't seem to fire off when a new subtitle appears on the screen. Is there any such event? Thank you everyone

Comment: Yes, it exists. As you pointed out, there is a `cuechange` event who fires when your track changes the current cue ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/cuechange),
 [HTML5Rocks --> Track and cue events](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/)). You are saying you tried it and it isn't working. Can you post some code to check your issue?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I was just coming back to post that it was my mistake. I was adding the cuechange event to the video not the track. thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome ;)